# Using the FB.ui function without an App ID?

Tags: facebook, app-id, fb.ui

Background: We have a municipal webpage where we can post announcements. I'd like to be able to also post those announcements to FB without having to log into FB and reposting everything - I want one-stop shopping.

As far as I understand, you need an App ID in order to use the FB.ui function. This wouldn't normally be an issue, but we have a fan page and not a user page, and I can't seem to access the Developer Section to generate an App ID.

I can get as far as https://developers.facebook.com/. When I register my phone, the Confirmation ID FB sends me is two digits too long. As an alternative, I go to the link they send, but just get redirected to my organization's Dashboard and can never get into the Dev section.

Is there any way to "fake" the App ID or do some sort of workaround to get to the Dev section so I can get the App ID, or am I out of luck?

Comment: Have you used your personal account to access the developer section? Creating apps is only possible with user accounts, not page/business accounts.

Comment: I can access through my personal account, but if I use an App ID generated from there, the FB.ui function will tie to my personal account, correct? Is there any way to create a personal account and tie it to the business account?

Comment: FB.ui resp the JS SDK only cares about the app id, not who created it. And no, apps always belong to a user, and not any other kind of account.

Comment: Ok, if the App ID is more of a verification for posting, then how does it know what wall to post on? I would think it used that App ID to point to a particular user's wall...

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/

Answer (score 0):

You should also be able to use a credit card instead of a phone number:

> https://secure.facebook.com/settings?tab=payments

There is no way to "fake" an App ID, that would open up the way for spammers immediately.

Without an App/ID, you cannot use FB.ui, but you can use the sharer.php:

> http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=[URL]

It´s just a simple link, the page you want to share has to be filled with Open Graph tags:

> http://ogp.me/

Comment: Well, I didn't mean fake as in bypass the security, but more of an alternative for a business account. Also, I don't have access to a CC number - this is a municipality, not a business.

Comment: i am not judging, just saying, no worries :) - so you have to use your personal account to create an app/id, as discussed in your question, this is the only way. but...i will edit my answer and add another solution.

Comment: No I understand - I was just stating my position. I'll try with an App ID generated in my account. That being said though, how does FB know what wall to put it on?

Comment: Thanks for the sharer.php - I'll take a look at it and see if I can get it to work!

Comment: well, with the FB.ui feed dialog you always post to your own wall. with the sharer.php, you can decide where to post. Btw, i added a site for the Open Graph tags now.